# how to decrypt webhook data in php?

Tags: php, openssl

i have this.. url https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/23910602/2s93z87NyL#e283c26e-3b94-4bf4-8d73-0e3a5dd8b7c1 here on webhook i have received

responce: `{"success":true,"status":200,"error":null,"data":"33c396e22d255a2edbf6b7538190e52295add20b74fbf1500ee360cba5c284783793d113d6cc735271b25804138e1d3b965a2adaa78eddgb17040382a9aa346344606d097317c90c3909649975b1abeca9e201514ffac32c3f34636b5900cd64596691b1c2b82ad2acb3464346dasdas63dasd36asdsf3634adsad34634663asasda70424dc4ba"}`

but here data is encrypted and i am not understanding how to decrypt this please read document and tell me how to du this..

i am tryed this but now working..

```
<?php

// Encrypted data
$encrypted_data = "33c396e22d255a2edbf6b7538190e52295add20b74fbf1500ee360cba5c284783793d113d6cc735271b25804138e1d3b965a2adaa78eddgb17040382a9aa346344606d097317c90c3909649975b1abeca9e201514ffac32c3f34636b5900cd64596691b1c2b82ad2acb3464346dasdas63dasd36asdsf3634adsad34634663asasda70424dc4ba";

// Client secret used for encryption
$client_secret = "client_secret";

// Attempt decryption
$decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_data), 'aes-256-cbc', $client_secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

if ($decrypted_data === false) {
    echo "Decryption failed: " . openssl_error_string();
} else {
    echo $decrypted_data;
}
```

Comment: Is there no _actual_ API documentation available, directly from whoever the provider of this service is?

Comment: That documentation says nothing at all about the `data` parameter, or what it's supposed to contain. Talk to the API maintainers if you're unsure. Asking us to guess is likely to be wildly unproductive for everyone involved.